# need help regarding ActionBar And Fragmentation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am using actionbarsherlock library to have action-bar in my application,

I am also using view-pager to switch between the page,

Now the problem is **i want only one tab with two fragment** to display data regarding each other.

What could be the possible way to do this?

I have been going through like the one below but unsuccessful

In main fragment i am inflating a xml like this

```
<code>
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.album_view_main, container, false);

        return fragView;
    }
</code>
```

xml fie is look like this

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_album_view"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        class="com.nix.music.activity.fragments.AlbumFragMent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_list_song"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</code>
```

but the problem is i cannot find "frame_list_song" in AlbumFragment class it appears null

what could be the way around ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This layout should be set in the parent *activity* using `setContentView()`. Then, you would be able to do something like `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frame_list_song)` from your `AlbumFragment`. The better way would be to use an interface and transfer control to the main activity, and not access other fragments directly.

Comment: means instead of inflating view i need to use setcontentView, am i correct?

Comment: No. The parent _activity_ should use this layout. The actual fragment needs it's own layout file (_not_ `album_view_main`, and you would use `inflate()` to create the view in `onCreateView()`. Read the docs about fragments again and study the example apps for details.

Comment: i have did the same thing that you have mentioned hear but the problem is it appears in all the tab and i want the two fragments in only one tab

Comment: Oh, I see. If you want to use a fragment for each tab, this cannot be done, since you cannot nest fragments (fragment within a fragment is impossible).

Comment: Write your own `ViewPagerImplementation` that doesn't use fragments.